# How rename multiple files adding one symbol at the end of files

Tags: python-3.x

How rename multiple files adding one symbol at the end of files

From this:

```
New Text Document.txt
New Text Document (2).txt
New Text Document (3).txt
New Text Document (4).txt
```

To this:

```
New Text Document1.txt
New Text Document2.txt
New Text Document3.txt
New Text Document4.txt
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With an input of

```
from os.path import splitext


file_list = ["New Text Document.txt", "New Text Document (2).txt",
             "New Text Document (3).txt", "New Text Document (4).txt"]
```

You get the desired output with

```
def parse(file, no):
    body, ext = splitext(file)
    new_body_str = ' '.join(body.split()[:3])
    return f"{new_body_str}{no}{ext}"

output_list = [parse(filename, no+1) for no, filename in enumerate(file_list)]
```

If you need this to work for other files than `New Text Document` use a regular expression instead of `body.split()[:3]`